# Replacing a bathvanity light with multiple fixtures

Tags: bathroom

I am replacing an eight bulb lighting strip in my bathroom with two LED four lamp strips and adding three small LED recessed cans.  The old strip when I bought the house, used 8 60 watt bulbs.  Two of the three LED recessed fixtures are 50 watt equivalents drawing 5.5 watts per fixture, the third 6.5.  Each of the four bulb LED replacement strips pulls 23 watts.  I ran the wire tested and have current at all five connection points. When I started the project I inadvertently grounded the switch and tripped the breaker.  Since I was replacing it anyway no big deal.  When I connected the fixtures the circuit popped both with the original and new switch. The wire coming off the switch is 14g and I ran all the new wiring using 12.  Is the wire the problem or am I missing something else?

Comment: You've tested for presence of hot power at the lights, have you tested for presence of neutral?

Comment: No, but all the neitral wires are securely connected to each other in the run as the hotel are.  Other that using two probe tester like I did to test hot I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are the neutrals of the fixtures connected to the neutrals  in the box? "When I started the project I inadvertently grounded the switch and tripped the breaker." **You did not have the breaker *OFF* when you started messing with the wires?**  What does inadvertently grounded mean ?

Comment: I had not moved any wires, just pulled the switch cover off and was testing current prior to starting work and grounded the probe.   I tested the neutrals last night, everything on both sides was properly connected and tight.  I hunted around on the web and it appears that I should be using 14/2 wire, stranded preferred due to voltage drop.  Thughts?